# How do I change a Document Library's Column Width?

Tags: document-library

How do I edit the column width of a document library (on the list view)?

I'm using SharePoint 2010 Foundation.

Comment: i found i had to add 'min-width:' to the style as per the link above to get this working for widening columns...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to make changes to "view/Allitems.aspx" form for your document library, if you follow this link, it will help you

[sharepoint-2010-how-to-change-width-of-list-column/](http://aanuwizard.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/sharepoint-2010-how-to-change-width-of-list-column/)

hope it helps ;)

Comment: Yes, it helped but I had to put !important in the width, overflow and white-space because ms-vh2 was overriding the styles. Thanks!

Comment: No problem and "!important" is a life saver trust me :)